# 'Critic' badge once allocated stays there though I am not eligible

Tags: discussion, badges, down-votes

I got the 'Critic' badge on my first down vote on a post.

But, soon I recognized that it was not appropriate to give a down vote for that post and revoked the same. And there is no down vote present from me all over the system at the moment.

But my user id is still decorated with the 'Critic' badge though I am not eligible as of the moment for the same.

Please have thought on this whether it is proper behavior or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular badges are forever. Once awarded, they are not taken away agan.<sup>*</sup>

The same is not true for tag specialist badges; they *are* taken away and re-awarded as needed.

<sup>*<sub>If you earned the badge through cheating, the site developers *can*, at their discretion, revoke badges.</sub></sup>

Comment: Revoking badges, does that happen ?

Comment: @AshRj: If gained through cheating, yes.

Comment: That I understood, but does it *actually* happen ? Anything here in Meta ?

Comment: @AshRj: See [How did someone get "Publicist" with 27 views?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129660/130135#130135)

Comment: So it does happen..